# How to use arduino and P-channel & N-channel MOSFET to control voltage to PT2264 address pins

Tags: arduino, mosfet, control, 12v, switching

Im looking to control a PT2264 RF transmitter module from an arduino so that I can transmit to different receivers. To do this I need to supply either +12v or 0v to the various address pins of the PT2264 IC depending on which receiver I am addressing. The code will be done in a way so that both mosfets are not saturated at the same time (ie avoid a dead short). I believe the current draw from the PT2262 to be minimal. My proposed solution is this:

[image: circuit diagram]

PT2262 datasheet: (http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/35122/PTC/PT2262.html)

Would this work in its current form?

Could both mosfets be switched by a single arduino pin?

Many thanks for any feedback.

Joe

Comment: Your image is terrible, you really think we can decipher a 150x100 pixel blob?

Comment: For such a simple circuit you can use this site's integrated circuit drawing program, look for the little schematic/circuit  symbol while editing/writing your question

Comment: That circuit puts 12V against the output, which 1) you don't want, and 2) won't work.

Comment: Better quality photo now uploaded - it shows up for me as full quality. I do not have access to a computer at presented so doing the best I can on a phone therefore I cant use the circuit drawing program.

Comment: Ignacio, I am intending to get 12v to the address pin with the p-mosfet as it must be logic 1 to "register" (the PT2262 is a 8-15v IC).

Comment: Don't use two FETs. Just use the N-channel to pull low and a simple pull-up resistor to pull high. Probably 10K.

Comment: You also don't really want 12V going to the Mega (3.3V?)'s pin.

Answer (score 1):

A push pull set up like you show is excessive, and could result in a near short if both outputs are active at the same time. A single npn or n channel mosfet, with a pull up to 12V would work. Essentially replacing the p channel mosfet with a 10k resistor is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Loose the P channel and associated resistor. Replace it with a 10k pullup. Good to go! Just remember that it is inverting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdQuZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transistor selection constraints (leave some room):

- Vgs,on < 3.3V
- Vds,max > 12V

Comment: Hmm... (checks time stamp) jinx!

Comment: Also your missing the node below the 10k above the source that goes to the IC.

Comment: @Passerby I noticed that too! I thought it was funny that we even picked the same value. I'll clarify that thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! Makes sense entirely and I feel an idiot for overcomplicating things. Much appreciated. Joe

Comment: No worries. You were on your way to inventing an H-bridge ;)

Comment: @HoustonFortney can you add to your answer saying that the gate drive voltage for this device needs to work with only 3.3V (From the ATMEGA Mega), meaning whatever N-channel FET is chosen, the Vgs_th should be definitely < 2.5V to ensure a decent on/off at 3.3V

Comment: The Arduino Mega runs at 5V.